# States on a matrix C* algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $M_{n}$ be the matrix algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ endowed with a structure of a C*-algebra with respect to the supremum norm and involution map $$*: M_{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$$
$$ A \mapsto \overline{A^{t}}$$

Let us consider a state, e.g. the map $f: M_{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ that is a positive linear functional of norm 1.

One asserts that $f$ is a state if and only if there exists a positive $S \in M_{n}$ with $Tr(S) = 1$ and $$f(T) = Tr(ST)$$

In fact, it can be showed that if $f$ is as follows, then it satisfies the definition of a state.
How to show the reverse statement?

I suppose that it is a reasonable approach to start with considering rank one projections (since these span the whole $M_{n}$). So we are succeed in  proving that all these projection are unitary equivalent then the statement holds.

Is it true and if not, what are the possible ways to approach the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if i succeed to deal with it, though it would be great to obtain a sort of a "peer review".

First, note that any linear functional $f: M_{n}(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is in fact of the form $$f(X) = \text{tr}(XA)$$ since $$\text{tr}(XA) = \sum_{ij}{X_{ij}A_{ij}}$$

Since all the states are the linear positive functional of norm 1 (by definition), we may apply the following result:

**Proposition**

Let $f$ be a functional on a C*-algebra. Then the following statements are equivalent:

(1) $f$ is positive

(2) For some approximate unit $(u_{\lambda})$  of $A$, $||f|| = \lim_{\lambda}{T(u_{\lambda})}$

(turn to a G. Murphy book for a proof)

Then since the sequence which constantly $1$ is an approximate unit, we derive that $f$ is positive if and only if $f(1) = ||f||$

So, assume that $f$ is a state, then $f(T) = \text{tr}(TS)$ for some $S$, by the preeciding proposition $f(1) = ||f|| = \text{tr}(S) = 1$, then $\text{tr}(S) = 1$.

Comment: Yes, this argument is correct. But you still need to show that $S$ is positive.